# Добавить колонку со значениями в зависимости от других

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня датафрейм, в нем две колонки с цифрами. Надо сделать третью колонку, в которой будет булево значение: если колонка `a` не отличается от колонки `b` на 5 % == True

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [100,101,103],
 'col_2': [95,94,97 ],
 'col_3': [True,False,False ],}
)
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: пробовали пользоваться знаками препинания?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [100, 101, 103],
                   'col_2': [95, 94, 97]})

df['col_3'] = df.col_2.div(df.col_1).between(0.95, 1.05)
print(df)
```

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    100     95   True
1    101     94  False
2    103     97  False
```

Comment: Не то, так не сработает

Comment: Что именно не сработает и почему? Исходные данные и результат соответствуют вопросу

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы навели меня на мысль и получилось